# Zygote Implantation and Pregnancy Detection

Tags: reproduction, embryology, reproductive-biology, pregnancy

In a normal pregnancy, the embryo (blastocyst) implants [between 8-9 days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_fertilization#/media/File:Human_Fertilization.png) after ovulation.  My understanding is that it is able to implant because the fertilized embryo produces a hormone that triggers the uterus to prepare for implantation.

1. At what point after this implantation can the first signs of pregnancy hormone be detected in the blood stream? (Hospital Birth Detection)
2. At what point after this implantation does the uterus prevent further embryo implantation